# Google Page speed test showing 0 page speed

Tags: page-speed

I tried to test the speed of a website and it appeared to show [0 speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Flabelleforme.co.uk%2F). Why would a site have 0 speed? Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not to be rude, but because **you score terribly for speed**. Images thát big? Those images sizes are INSANE. Kinda harsh, but how did you even manage this?

To solve this, **follow their suggestions** as much as possible and your rank will increase. The list they give **is a very good start**.

You should at least:

- Opitimize images. This is the first thing. Just drop your images in [kraken.io](http://kraken.io), they'll do it for you. *Save your images for web* if you use Photoshop, don't just save as jpg.
- Caching more than 24 hours, at least 1 week, I suggest you read about caching and best practices. Longer is better
- Find a way to speed up your site. 4,8sec isn't doable in 2015 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Following functions could help you hopefully a little on your way, because [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/labelleforme.co.uk/dkYmlLdn) is also not that happy.

**Remove query strings from static resources (?ver=x.x.x)** 
[Text source Gtmetrix.com](https://gtmetrix.com/remove-query-strings-from-static-resources.html)

> Most proxies, most notably Squid up through version 3.0, do not cache
>   resources with a "?"  in their URL even if a Cache-control: public
>   header is present in the response.  To enable proxy caching for these
>   resources, remove query strings from references to static resources, 
>   and instead encode the parameters into the file names themselves.

This function takes care of that, add to `functions.php`

```
function remove_version_parameter( $src ){
    // Check if version parameter exist
    $parts = explode( '?ver', $src );
    // return without version parameter
    return $parts[0];
}
// filter .js files
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'remove_version_parameter', 15, 1 );
// filter .css files
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'remove_version_parameter', 15, 1 );
```

**Defer parsing of JavaScript files**
[Text source Gtmetrix.com](https://gtmetrix.com/defer-parsing-of-javascript.html)

> In order to load a page, the browser must parse the contents of all
>    tags,  which adds additional time to the page load. By
>   minimizing the amount of JavaScript  needed to render the page, and
>   deferring parsing of unneeded JavaScript until it  needs to be
>   executed, you can reduce the initial load time of your page.

Following function takes care of that, add to `functions.php`

```
function add_defer_to_js( $url ) {

        if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) {
        return $url;
        }

        // Must be a ', not "!
        return "$url' defer='defer";
    }
}
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'add_defer_to_js', 11, 1 );
```

Just a note:

- Do not resize your images with css, just make them the size as needed and add at least the `width` to them.
- Take a look [here](https://gtmetrix.com/wordpress-optimization-guide.html) for some information about how to do 'stuff'. (optimization)
- Use the hints from other answers also and you will do pretty well afterwards.